# How to use access tokens to get authorization to access REST APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an HttpClient that I am using for a REST API. I get the access token from the server but I do not have permission to use the REST APIs. The response is `Error: Unauthorized`

First, Using `getAccessToken()` method, I get the access token.

```
   public static async Task<string> getAccessToken()
    {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "http://admin.altrabo.com/");

            var tokenClient = new TokenClient()
            {
              client_Id= -1,
              username= "admin",
              password= "Main@dm!n",
              grant_Type= "Main@dm!n",
              externalProvider= 1,
 
            };

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<TokenClient>("https://api.altrabo.com/api/v1/token", tokenClient);
            var json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AccessToken>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            return json.access_token;
   }
```

which returns the access token.

Then, using the `verifyToken()` method, I verify the access token.

```
public static async Task<string> verifyToken(string access_token)
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.altrabo.com/api/v1/verifyToken");
  return response.ReasonPhrase;          
}
```

returns `OK`

But when I want to get access to API, I encounter `Error: Unauthorized`.

For example when I want to get the list of airports:

```
public static async Task<string> ListAirports()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    return await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.altrabo.com/api/v1/BaseData/GetAirports?pageSize=1000&pageNumber=1");
}
```

The API documentation is available at
[https://www.getpostman.com/collections/51cd9e7f5f6ebafa8c48‎](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/51cd9e7f5f6ebafa8c48%E2%80%8E)

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to be available openly online. It makes it very difficult to help

Comment: @John The documentation is available at https://www.getpostman.com/collections/51cd9e7f5f6ebafa8c48‎

Comment: Have you tried including the token in the request to get the airports? I mean, add the token as a Request Header, in the same manner you do as when you verify the token?

Comment: @Mustafa Great! :-)  I've added that as an answer. Feel free to upvote it and/or mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the token to the request to get the airports, in the same manner you do, as when you verify the token.

```
public static async Task<string> ListAirports(string access_token)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
    return await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.altrabo.com/api/v1/BaseData/GetAirports?pageSize=1000&pageNumber=1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the documentation of the rest-api for what authorization-method the api requires. Maybe its username/password or something.

https://username:token@your-api.com